# How to infer the rest argument type for function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm super confused why I can't seem to narrow down my rest argument from variadic tuples.

```
type Arr<A> = A extends [infer I, ...infer Rest]
    ? [I, ...Arr<Rest>]
    : []

function schema<const A extends any[]>(...args: Arr<A>) {
    return args
}

const a = schema('foo', 'bar') // Error: Expected 0 arguments, got 2
```

One would guess that this should be fairly straightforward and narrow down, but sadly there seems to be a difference between how arrays / tuples and rest argument tuples get narrowed down.

```
type A = Arr<['foo', 'bar']> // works
type Spread = Arr<[...['foo', 'bar']]> // also works
type F = Arr<Parameters<<A>(...args: Arr<A>) => A>> // doesn't work
```

When I just put `A`  as `type Arr<A> = .... ? ... : A` then it correctly works, but there's weird stuff happening in terms of typing, treating it as `args_0`, `args_1`, etc.

[image]

This obviously is also why the error is happening, I'm just wondering if there's any way to type this properly.

Here's the [link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAPDAfFAvLKEAewIB2AJgM5QDaAlgQGYRxQCSANFAHQfV0MBKEJwALoAoAJAB+Ci3Yd4SPgJQjRALgojhNAK4EAxsEoB7AlBK6AFhAC2AQ0S7jArLnzEyNgiHKCUACg5sNnAA5iRqcsgoAJRQAN5icBDAWnAmQaHCAL7Cwg4ETjYYphbWNr4A5DSGhuWs5QBGQeVROaCQWJgR5JXVtVANTT5QAPTDUADuhnAA1iTCbdAAymCJNkRFXQHdVTV1jXDlgkOjUDYANiSGE1Oz8+DQAGIbCIgACkE2Vkn0JIiR-hx0mFYC9UDF0GhUGgTkRDPwCOVgNcZkA)

---

**EDIT**: I tried to keep it as simple and as vague/general as possible in original question - *(minimal reproducible example)*, but as pointed out, the code in my example kind of makes no sense (essentially `type Arr` could just be `readonly unknown[]` for all intents and purposes in that case).

Here's where an example, where it can't just be resolved by it (i.e. i need to transform the type from A to B while knowing individual items of the rest params)

These are the definitions which work fine and specify what will be passed as arguments to my problematic `wrapper` function

```
type Args = readonly unknown[]
type Fn = (...args: Args) => any

// we need to be able to infer the function parameters and returntype 
// the method itself is not important, just the type
const paramfn = <K extends string, F extends Fn>(key: K, fn: F): [K, F] => [key, fn]
```

Here's where I have issues with the typing

```
// Now I need to type my arg functions, where each can have different param types and different returns

// First these should narrow it down that arguments of my wrapper function should be
// the same as the result of my paramFn function
type FnArray<A extends Args> =  A extends [infer ParamFnResult, ...infer Rest]
    ? ParamFnResult extends [infer K, infer F]
        ? [[K, F], ...FnArray<Rest>]
        : FnArray<Rest>
    : []

// This will be the result of the wrapper function
type FnMap<A extends Args> = A extends [infer ParamFnResult, ...infer Rest]
    ? ParamFnResult extends [infer K, infer F]
        ? { [key in K as string]: F } & FnMap<Rest>
        : FnMap<Rest>
    : {}

// This would be how the wrapper function would be defined, where the typing issues occur
// Basically I need to map the types of individual rest params of ...paramFunctions
// and know each key and parameter and returntype of the fn in the [key, fn] pairs
const wrapper = <A extends Args>(...paramFunctions: FnArray<A>) => {
    return paramFunctions.reduce(
        (res, [key, fn]) => ({
            ...res,
            [key]: fn,
        }), {} as FnMap<A>
    )
}

// This is however an issue when trying to pass these arguments
// However my function expects 0 arguments instead of the 2 from the rest param
// The issue stems from the fact, that FnArray is typed incorrectly.
// because it expects args_0 to be ['1', () => string] and args_1 to be ['2', () => string]
// however it's unable to infer the correct types as these mismatch the first line of 
// FnArray<A> as these DO NOT ExTEND [infer ParamFn, ...inferRest]
wrapper(paramfn('1', () => '1'), paramfn('2', () => '2'))
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ZGNiGkGGI2WoxXa8XSUFk1BU6-R-mi4n32dJ9b0rOMayrOsGyLABvW57lsHgxiwOZgAWAgECYE4oAAXygAAyL1LzAEcczHCdJ0Iq9R3HCjoOwlkNDnBdNANfRTAxD5dw1LUXQhY8WIFNjcQgew7D0WF4SsVJ2EWQobRzbdPE8WIXgAIWQmw0RXUhvl+fRrCCfd13JSAlQKOw8SxGwcDILBV2tEoAnfMyvyEJynVdKEkBeSIoGoD5sGRPy9gUKl3PSDNfMZOJAR3VIBgQ4y7j2R5rgCdlvK6aESj3A9nGGANgODeBQ0ENyk087oB07P0YFkGRUHkaCJ2inhws4SroQETAbM8CA+HIvhrTqZKHjBJ4GvkPhmrzWbU2G8i81GzDxpqcjsKkOo6IUTYCCI-0aKkFh6JeJiUGYvktBxZx0QXeTNDcKU4BAWTrACJBLTcbk5QVHIXgACToCBrodI8oVWSBvBQAAGBREHlelzuy7B9Di6AACYwVFIJjIcx0glO1I7rIaBmggIIUHsbHjPsJFalcGUvRqwoTL+OwuiHCBvBIAQXlMNEmmgcVJkhnI4eQAB9WHrHYhgAHIAEY5bqPhJp5VDFmuXyQSQCWFf+Nd5fR5X+DV+ZNZeS7gYzbI5ZQChzEsA3X1NDnMG8VmIk+nNoCCBdDOAILTVEjkSiIMTtwKF4OyHLsDp29duQAEQAeTeFOZygABRCYZyz14k9uV8AKdAg2zTCDfxYXKtT4cKBj4RWTdVm4m82-GG7l42VbVru5akKQgA)

Comment: `F` doesn't work because in order for it to "work" it would need to return `A`... which doesn't make sense since `A` is a type parameter that hasn't been given an argument yet.

Comment: Say, if it was only strings allowed anyways, you could use this: https://tsplay.dev/mpQpbW

Comment: In addition to the `F` issue pointed out above, there's some distracting stuff here that stops me from understanding the question properly. 1: `Arr<A>` seems like a no-op, so I'm not sure why you'd use it over just `A`. 2: The `const` type param modifier will tend to cause `readonly` array inference which will fail to match `any[]` and things will not behave as expected, which has nothing to do with `Arr<A>` at all.  If I fix both of those I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3V6bN), which "works" but then I don't know what the question is supposed to be about.  Could you [edit] to clear these up?

Comment: @jcalz and @kelsny, yeah I get your point. I tried to make it as minimal for an easily reproducible example, because the typing in my actual issue is bit more complex as you can see from the edit. Essentially it narrows down to the issue, I need to be able to narrow it down to be able to infer each individual argument types for the spread as they can each differ. I got it working when I made my second argument an object (map) instead of the rest / spread, but I dislike the syntax because it enforces redundant key names (i.e.) `{ foo: query('foo', fooFunction) }`

Comment: There has to be something of intermediate complexity that still demonstrates the issue you're seeing. (First it was raw meat and now it's burnt. Could you do medium rare?)  In starting to parse that I see that there is no way `query('foo', foo)` will be able to infer anything useful for `R`, so having it present is just a distraction to whatever you're actually asking about with tuple spread inference. Could you possibly tighten this up? It's up to you of course, and maybe others will be fine with this as-is, but I prefer a [mre] to clearly exhibit the issue without distractions.

Comment: …cont'd: oh and in `type Query<F extends Fn, R = ReturnType<F>> = <SK extends string>(schemaKey: SK, ...args: Parameters<F>) => R` there is nothing useful `SK` can be doing there, at all. It appears exactly once in the call signature, so it might as well be just `(schemaKey: string, ...args: Parameters<F>) => R`.  I will disengage now and look again if this question is edited to remove unrelated problems. Maybe you could just add something to your original example so `Arr` is not merely a no-op. Or again, you could keep it as-is and maybe someone else will be more of a help to you.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I tried to keep it as 'medium rare' as possble for it to be minimal but still make sense in the now-revised edit. Let me know if the issue is any clearer, essentially it comes down to the fact, that I need to be able to infer each individual item in the spread / rest params array and from them I need to be able to perform operations on them which transform the type to different one (in this case, from array to object map)

Comment: The code in your new example can be collapsed down [to this version here](https://tsplay.dev/wQbYGN).  I have yet to see any motivation for the kind of recursive variadic tuple stuff that's been going on in your examples, so maybe you actually don't need it and are just looking how to mapping an array of key-value pairs to an object type?  Is that it, and the whole "inferring rest argument for a function" thing is a red herring?  If so I'm happy to write up an answer but maybe you could [edit] to ask directly about that use case instead of inferring rest arguments. If not, I think I'm stumped.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, yeah you're right was a red herring after all. Just didn't occur to me that it can be simplified, since I didn't know you can access the individual properties with `as` keyword in a type declaration (i.e. `[T in Q[number] as T[0]]`) as obviously the tuple consists of two elements, but I kind of blanked on the fact in typescript it doesn't matter with the as assertion as long as you return the correct type for the key,value pairs. Thanks and aplologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to do just

```
import { UnionToIntersection } from 'type-fest'
// type UnionToIntersection<Union> = (Union extends unknown ? (distributedUnion: Union) => void : never) extends (mergedIntersection: infer Intersection) => void ? Intersection : never

type FromEntries<A extends readonly (readonly [PropertyKey, unknown])[]> =
    | UnionToIntersection<
        { [K in keyof A]: { [P in A[K][0]]: A[K][1] } }[number]
    >
type Pure<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown
function fromEntries<const A extends readonly (readonly [string, Function])[]>(entries: A): Pure<FromEntries<A>> {
    return Object.fromEntries(entries) as any
}

const obj = fromEntries([
    // ^?
    ['a', () => true],
    ['b', () => false],
])
// const obj: {
//     a: () => true;
//     b: () => false;
// }
```

Is that what you want?